# NEST how to setup completion suggestion context using annotation

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I"m trying to setup context for my completion suggestion attribute on my POJO class however, most of the documentation online are based on configuration setting. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
[Completion]
 public CompletionField Suggest { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For indexing:

```
[Completion(Name = "FieldNameSuggest")]
    public CompletionField Suggest
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data.AddRange(new List<string>() {"word1",word2"word3",... });//for suggest
            return new CompletionField()
            {
                Input = data,
                Weight = 1
            };
        }
    }
```

For get suggest:

Query Making:

```
var sugContainer = new SuggestContainer
            {
                { "completion-suggest", new SuggestBucket
                    {
                        Prefix ="word",//text for search
                        Completion = new CompletionSuggester
                        {
                            //Fuzzy = new FuzzySuggester
                            //{
                            //    Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
                            //    MinLength = 1,
                            //    PrefixLength = 2,
                            //    Transpositions = true,
                            //    UnicodeAware = false
                            //},
                            Analyzer = "simple",
                            Field =new Field("FieldNameSuggest"),
                            Size =10, //SuggestionCount
                            SkipDuplicates=true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Finaly for search:

```
 var Result = Client.Search<T>(new SearchRequest<T>
            {
                Suggest = sugContainer ,
                ...
            });
```

Comment: This isn't related to my question. My question was how can I add `Category Context` to my existing CompletionField?